# AWS Lambda serverless Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

my problem is that the python dependencies of my function are too heavy for being upload, as I´m reaching the 250 MB limit. As I´m only using certain parts of the packages I would be grateful if anyone can  tell me how to only include that. Here is my requirements.txt: `netCDF4 numpy==1.20.2 pandas   shapely sklearn uuid datetime geopy`

from both sklearn and geopy I only want 1 function.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SO.

I had this exact problem with those exact packages more or less, now you can go through and pick out the code you want from them, however, balderman's answer should be the one you use as it's scalable.

Comment: OR just paste those functions into your own code, but you'll need to bring any related code in with it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a "container image" - the size limit is 10GB.

> you can now package and deploy Lambda functions as container images of up to 10 GB in size. In this way, you can also easily build and deploy larger workloads that rely on sizable dependencies, such as machine learning or data intensive workloads. Just like functions packaged as ZIP archives, functions deployed as container images benefit from the same operational simplicity, automatic scaling, high availability, and native integrations with many services.

Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I have many lambda functions that are connected by SQS, so I would need a way to deploy the entire application as an image. Do you have any tutorial that I can follow for that?